# Linking to app on Android Market without using package name

Tags: android, google-play

I have a problem. I didn't realise the package name of the Android application would be visible to the public when linking to the app listing in the online market.

e.g. https://market.android.com/details?id=**com.mycompanyname.android.appname**

My client who commissioned the app is not happy with this (they are making a decision as I type this). Is there any way to make a URL that opens the market place listing without using the package name?

It will take hours for me to change the name and retest the app <strike>and regenerate several API keys/hashes etc.</strike> which will mean I will miss the delivery deadline.

Foiled at the finish line!

Update: You don't need to regenerate keys for the Facebook API, Xtify API or Google Maps API when you change the package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is any way to avoid showing the package name.

Comment: Yeah there isn't. I had to change the package name, re-test and resubmit my app. Another gotcha I noticed on the new Motorola Razr: the e-mail address that you use to create the signing certificate is also shown in the market app entry. Lesson learned: always keep *everything* on brand.